# Red5 server only records first few seconds of RTMP video feed from AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air, video-capture, red5, rtmp

I am testing a new installation of Red5 server using the oflaDemo that is installed. I am wanting to publish a live video feed to be recorded to a file. This seems to work ok except for the fact that only a fraction of the video feed is ever recorded. Only the first frame for videos of around 30 seconds ever seems to be available to play back and only a few seconds of video is recorded for longer (~10 minutes) of video.

What could cause Red5 out of the box to only record a few seconds of video?

------------ Heres a code snippet -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
nc.connect("rtmp://myurl");
nc.client = this;

ns_out = new NetStream( nc );
ns_out.attachCamera( cam )

protected function onNetStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void
    { 
        switch(event.info.code)
        {

            case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                ns_out.publish(_filename, "record"); 


            break;

        }

    }
```

Comment: What does the client code look like?

Comment: ive edited my question to include the bare bones of my code. thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me this is a bug in the latest version of Red5. I have the same issue with an audio recorder app. Although I used to record streams with no problems in older versions of Red5.

Comment: oh great thanks - do you know what version you were using? i might try and find it and do some tests... thanks for the response!

Comment: Thanks - we installed an older version of Red5 and it worked perfectly. this is definitely a bug in the latest version. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Hey, how did you install an older version of red5? I'm having the same problem, but the only instructions I can find that work install the newest revision, no matter what it is.

Comment: you can find the old versions here: http://www.red5.org/downloads/red5/ for me v0.8 worked great.